# Cancelling submit on enter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to cancel a submit when I click enter in an `ASP:TextBox` element which is performing `asyncpostback` when text is changed and make it click on other button instead. I use the same Javascript function for all of my textboxes, but the others are defined as regular `input` elements and do not have any `asyncpostback` method. It works with each of the textboxes but not with the `asp:TextBox` one. I'm not sure why, but I'd be glad if you knew how to fix this issue. When I click enter in the textbox, it updates asynchronously as it should, but immediately refreshing the page.

This is my code:

```js
function cancel_enter(elem) {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("btnReg").focus();
        document.getElementById("btnReg").click();
        if (elem != null)
            elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    return true;
}
```

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="user_info_all" runat="server">
            <table dir="rtl" style="text-align:left;" id="table_user" runat="server">
                <tr>
                  <td>שם משתמש:</td>
                  <td><asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox TextMode="SingleLine" ID="reg_user" runat="server" MaxLength="50" OnTextChanged="reg_user_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="input-validation" id="reg_user_v" runat="server"></div></ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReg" /></Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>סיסמא:</td>
                  <td><div class="tooltip" title="הסיסמא חייבת להכיל 8 תווים לפחות">
                    <input class="tooltip" title="" type="Password" ID="reg_pass" runat="server" maxlength="50" onkeypress="return cancel_enter(this);" onkeyup="ValidateEmailPass(this);" /></div>
                    <div class="input-validation" id="reg_pass_v"></div></td></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>אימייל:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="reg_email" runat="server" maxlength="100" onkeypress="return cancel_enter(this);" onkeyup="ValidateEmailPass(this);" />
                    <div class="input-validation" id="reg_email_v"></div></td></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>גיל:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="reg_age" maxlength="2" runat="server" onkeypress="return cancel_enter(this);" onkeyup="ValidateEmailPass(this);" />
                    <div class="input-validation" id="reg_age_v"></div></td></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan='2' style="text-align:center"><asp:UpdatePanel ID="RegisterBtn" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnReg" OnClientClick="return HideForm(this);" OnClick="btnReg_Click" Text="הירשם" UseSubmitBehavior="true" /></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReg" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Why is it still refreshing the page after I click enter?

Comment: The default behavior in a regular textbox is enter = submit (I think), in a textarea it's a newline. Is it the same keycode on both inputs?

Comment: `asp:TextBox` is not a textarea.. It's also defined `TextMode="SingleLine"`. I'll check about the keycode though..

Comment: Could you post the code for the reg_user_TextChanged method?

Comment: @Tim I've added a `window.alert(window.event.keyCode);` in the function, but it seems to not alert when I click enter in the `asp:TextBox` element..

Comment: The code for reg_user_TextChanged works without refreshing the page if the textbox loses focus (without clicking enter).

Answer (score 0):

There is an explicit call to `click` for the submit button:

```
function cancel_enter(elem) {
    // ...
    document.getElementById("btnReg").click();
    // ...
}
```

Remove this line as it's excplicitly makes your button to submit the page.

Comment: I want it to submit. It works with an Ajax method from C# and updates without refreshing the page. I just don't want it to refresh when pressing enter in my `asp:TextBox` element.

Comment: Do it works if you remove this method? Or it still refreshing the page?

Comment: If I click enter while in the `asp:TextBox` element, it won't call the javascript at all. I checked it by adding `window.alert(..)` into it. It instantly calls the ajax method and refreshing..

Comment: Try to search the asp.net `form` tag being added silently to your page, and call it's `submit` instead of `click` for the button.

Comment: The form's submit button is different. Moreover, everything works fine and it updates asynchronously unless I click enter in the username textbox. It even updates the username without refreshing the page when I click the button with the mouse or enter in any of the other textboxes.

Comment: That's because there is a `ASP.NET` handler for the `click` event which you have to find and call.